# Delegate nullified when present viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

With these codes, I set the delegate for the ViewController that is about to be presented. Based the logged result, the delegate is not nil when is assigned to the viewController.

```
NewEventViewController *NewEventView = (NewEventViewController *)[[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddView"];
NewEventView.delegate = self;
NSLog(@"delegate %@", NewEventView.delegate);
[self presentViewController:NewEventView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here is my declaration of protocol in NewEventViewController.

```
@protocol NewEventDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)addNewEventToProject:(Events *)event;
-(void)addProject:(Projects *)project;
@end
```

I declared a delegate like this

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <NewEventDelegate> delegate;
```

When the viewController is presented, the delegate seems to be nullified. I logged the delegate with `NSLog(@"Delegate %@", self.delegate);` the outcome is Delegate (null) What is the problem in my code.

My purpose is to call the delegate method when the viewcontroller is dismissed. The delegate method will pass back a Event object that will be added to my Realm database. Thank you very much!

Comment: can you show how you declare your delegate in NewEventView

Comment: try to make `NewEventView` class variable instead of local one

Comment: what you want exactly ?

Comment: You should have a delegate property declared in the header file as well (as @balkaransingh mentioned). '@property (nonatomic, weak) id <NewEventDelegate> delegate'

Comment: I did declare a delegate property.

Comment: Do you have another class named NewEventView? Variable names are normally lowercase and would not be highlighted. Can you confirm that the NewEventView is actually the view controller class you expect? Is the correct class type set in Storyboard?

Comment: No, NewEventView is the only one. I would suspect that when I assigned the delegate object, it got automatically deallocated or something like that.

Comment: Why did you opt to use `assign` in the delegate property declaration? Delegates are object types and are normally declared as a `weak` reference.

Comment: I tested using `assign` in the delegate property delcaration and the compiler gives a warning "Assigning retained object to unsafe property, object will be released after assignment".

Comment: so, what should I do in this case? Thank you for the comment!